# I am having an issue reviewing the bootstrap card that displays reviews on my web app using MongoDB, pyhton and angular. is an issue with review ID

Tags: python, angular, mongodb, api

I can't get the reviews to displays on a bootstrap card within my web app. I am getting several errors on the front end. Below is the examples, I feel the issue is with my get function that calls on the reviews to be displayed to the front end.

Back end

```
@app.route("/api/v1.0/movies/<string:id>/movie_reviews", methods=["GET"])
def get_movie_reviews(id):
    data_to_return = []
    movie = moviescollection.find_one( { "_id" : ObjectId(id) }, { "movie_reviews": 1, "_id": 0 } )
    for movie_reviews in movie["movie_reviews"]:
        movie_reviews["_id"] = str(movie_reviews["_id"])
        data_to_return.append(movie_reviews)
    return make_response( jsonify( data_to_return ), 200 )
```

Movies.component.html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="card bg-light mb-3" *ngFor="let review of webService.reviews_list | async">
                <div class="card-header">
                    Review by {{ review.name }}
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    {{ review.description }}
                    <hr>
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div> 
</div>
```

Movies.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { WebService } from './web.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'movies',
    templateUrl: './movies.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./movies.component.css']
})

export class MoviesComponent {
    constructor(public webService: WebService,
        private route: ActivatedRoute) { }
    ngOnInit() {
        this.webService.getMovies();
        this.webService.getReviews(
            this.route.snapshot.params.id);
        this.webService.moviesSubject
            .subscribe(movies => {
                this.movie_list = movies
                console.log(this.movie_list)
            })
    };

    
    movie_list;
}
```

webserive.ts

```
export class WebService {
    private movie_list;
    moviesSubject = new Subject();
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
    getMovies() {
        return this.http.get(
            'http://localhost:5000/api/v1.0/movies')
            .subscribe(response => {
                this.movie_list = response;
                this.moviesSubject.next(this.movie_list);
            })
    }

    getMovie(id) {
        return this.http.get(
            'http://localhost:5000/api/v1.0/movies/' + id)
            .toPromise();

    }

    private reviews_private_list;
    private reviewsSubject = new Subject<any>();
    reviews_list = this.reviewsSubject.asObservable();


    getReviews(id) {
        return this.http.get(
            'http://localhost:5000/api/v1.0/movies/' + id +
            '/movie_reviews')
            .subscribe(
                response => {
                    this.reviews_private_list = response;
                    this.reviewsSubject.next(
                        this.reviews_private_list);
                }
            )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to return the response as HttpResponse